# Creating .gif file

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, gif

I have a task to store and retrieve a .gif file in c#. I have successfully stored the gif in the database. I transformed it to binary file and use a stored procedure to store in the database.

Here is my code:

```
public int Insert(byte[] Byte,string Name,int userid)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand storedProcCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert", con);
        storedProcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        storedProcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bytes", banner2Byte);
        storedProcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", bannerName);
        storedProcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
        con.Open();
        storedProcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the byte array from the database and convert into a `.gif` and create the file I stored at the first place?

```
public int Retrieve(int id)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand storedProcCommand = new SqlCommand("Retrieve", con);
        storedProcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        storedProcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = storedProcCommand.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        byte[] arrays = reader.getBytes();             

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposed you had stored the gif file correctly (with header and all) you can use this function to get back an Image from the byte array.

```
public Image bytearr2image(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```